# How to print in hexadecimal,decimal and octal form a constant in C

Tags: c, constants

I'm having some issues resolving one of my assignments.I have searched documentation on the web but I cannot find a concise answer.

I have to print a constant e.g.123456789  in hexadecimal,decimal and octal form.

I know that 0x is for hexadecimal,0 for decimal and nothing for octal.Yet I have no ideea how to print it.I have used the #define method to define my constant

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define CONST 123456789
int main()
{
 printf("%d",0xCONST);
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: You're confusing the syntax used when C parses your text into a number, with how to make C create text that represents a number. Those are completely different things.

Comment: Also, in C syntax 0123 is octal and 123 decimal, not the other way around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read up on the `printf` *format specifiers* on the [printf man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CONST 123456789

int main()
{
    printf("%d = %#x = %#o\n", CONST, CONST, CONST);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and test:

```
$ gcc -Wall dec-hex-oct.c && ./a.out 
123456789 = 0x75bcd15 = 0726746425
$
```